# Valgrind aborting with the "killed" message

Tags: c++, valgrind

I have a centos4.1, I try to run valgrind for my binary(Takes significant amount of memory). Every time the process is getting aborted with the "killed" message. The dump file is also generated, but when I try to debug this dump file with gdb, it simply shows the "no symbol found" error. What could be the cause? 
And also it doesn't seem to use the swap memory(15 GB).
It is working fine for simple programs though.

Any help is appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Have a look at this one : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1950685/debugging-a-core-produced-by-valgrind

Comment: thanx @vcp, shall do that. I'll get back afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably the result of the system running out of memory and subsequently killing the largest process as the likely culprit.

You should be able to avoid this by adding swap space (of course, real memory will help too). Valgrind generates quite a bit of overhead in memory use because it needs to set aside inaccessible areas between allocations in order to trap out-of-bounds accesses.

Comment: Thanks @simon.I check but valgrind's memory management unit is not providing any error, as of now.

Comment: No, if the program allocates 10 bytes of memory, valgrind will allocate 42 bytes (10 + twice the `--redzone-size` argument, which defaults to 16 for *memcheck*), so the entire computer will run out of free pages. If you check the kernel log using `dmesg`, there should be a mention of that.